# Jsoup checkbox submit

Tags: android, jsoup

fairly new to Jsoup, i am trying to check this check-box

```
<input style="border:0px" type="checkbox" name="ClearOther" value="Y"id="ClearOtherID">
```

and then press this button

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Select" onclick="return WrapUp();">
```

i have had success with buttons so i don't think my code there is a problem but i am not sure if i am doing the check-box correctly.

```
.data("ClearOther","Y")
.data("Select","Submit")
```

Answer (score 0):

For a checkbox in a form, if you check it then its name and value will be submitted, if you don't check it then it is simply ignored (not submitted at all). So you should be on the right track, I've used checkboxes in my Jsoup project like you did and it worked well.